Angular 18. Error node_module this.http.get(configUrl).subscribe(data => {
I am developing an Angular app to connect with Alfresco. I am encountering a problem that did not occur in previous versions of Angular. When the app loads, Alfresco core fetches the configuration through an app.config.json file. This request is made through the @alfresco/adf-core function.
load(callback) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const configUrl = `app.config.json?v=${Date.now()}`;
    if (this.status === Status.INIT) {
      this.status = Status.LOADING;
      this.http.get(configUrl).subscribe(data => {
        this.status = Status.LOADED;
        this.config = Object.assign({}, this.config, data || {});
        callback?.();
        resolve(data);
        this.onDataLoaded();
      }, () => {
        console.error('app.config.json contains validation errors');
        resolve(this.config);
      });
    } else if (this.status === Status.LOADED) {
      resolve(this.config);
    } else if (this.status === Status.LOADING) {
      this.onLoad.subscribe(() => {
        resolve(this.config);
      });
    }
  });
}


The problem is that it does not reach the this.http.get(configUrl).subscribe request and jumps to the error. I don't understand the reason because it works in previous versions of Angular. The request is not made, and I have verified that the URL is correct.
Any idea what might be going wrong?
Here is my app.config.ts:
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({ eventCoalescing: true }),
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient(withFetch()),
    provideAnimations(),
    importProvidersFrom(
      TranslateModule.forRoot({
        loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useClass: TranslateLoaderService,
        },
      }),
      CoreModule.forRoot(),
    ),
  ],
};

And the ngModule from previous versions:
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { initialNavigation: 'enabledNonBlocking', relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy' }),
    // ADF modules
    CoreModule.forRoot(),
    ContentModule.forRoot(),
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useClass: TranslateLoaderService }
    })
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DocumentsComponent,
    AppLayoutComponent,
    FileViewComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    PreviewService,
    {
      provide: TRANSLATION_PROVIDER,
      multi: true,
      useValue: {
        name: 'app',
        source: 'resources'
      }
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}

adf-core.mjs:6991 app.config.json contains validation errors
that's what happens every time I run the application. But the get request is never triggered.
Edit: Complete error
adf-core.mjs:7011 app.config.json contains validation errors Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS. Find more at https://angular.dev/errors/NG0200
    at throwCyclicDependencyError (core.mjs:964:9)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:3127:9)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3005:23)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:1095:36)
    at ɵɵinject (core.mjs:1101:40)
    at inject (core.mjs:1186:10)
    at http.mjs:1777:28
    at http.mjs:1745:84
    at runInInjectionContext (core.mjs:3300:12)
    at http.mjs:1745:46


print the error. it should show something descriprive }, (err) => {         console.error('app.config.json contains validation errors', err);         resolve(this.config);       });

adf-core.mjs:7011 app.config.json contains validation errors Error: NG0200: Circular dependency in DI detected for InjectionToken HTTP_INTERCEPTORS. Find more at https://angular.dev/errors/NG0200
at throwCyclicDependencyError (core.mjs:964:9)
at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:3127:9)
at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3005:23)
at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:1095:36)
at ɵɵinject (core.mjs:1101:40)
at inject (core.mjs:1186:10)
at http.mjs:1777:28
at http.mjs:1745:84
at runInInjectionContext (core.mjs:3300:12)
at http.mjs:1745:46
